# Hiding email address in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

When you've got Windows 8 'metro' interface open it's got your MS Account right at the top for the world to see.  I often use my laptop in public places and I'm not keen on having my primary email address visible to anyone sat next to me.  Is there a way to hide (or at least rename it?)

Comment: If you put in your first and last name to your account on your Microsoft profile page, then your name will show in place of your email address. I had the same issue.

Comment: I have both my full name AND email showing...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to log on your microsoft account and fill out your first and last name, then log off and back in.

After that, your name will appear instead of your email.

Alternatively you could convert your live account [to a local account](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65YlUiaCbR4), but that would obviously stop the syncing with Microsoft services.

Comment: If this still throws up paranoia alarms, Use an alias when you fill in your name.

Answer (score 2):

I guess Liath is talking about the email address displayed under the full name on lock screen. Don't think currently it is possible to hide that. That's really annoying!

Comment: And also when you entering the password after 'choose user' screen. Annoying truly.