# How to hide or remove email address from Windows 8 lockscreen?

Tags: windows-8, email, lock-screen, microsoft-account

I'm using Windows 8 and I have an Microsoft account (@outlook.com). I was wondering if there is a way to remove or hide my email address from the lockscreen.

**Note:** I don't want to use a local account, just to hide my email address. I also know about [Hiding email address in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/498047/hiding-email-address-in-windows-8), but I'm asking specifically about the lockscreen.

Comment: I don't think its possible yet.

Answer (score 2):

I know only a way to hide all info:

1. Type regedit in Start Screen then open Registry Editor
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
3. Set `dontdisplaylastusername` to 1
4. Right click then create a DWORD `DontDisplayLockedUserID` with value of 3

Then all info here will hidden, and will need fill both username and password to login. Username can use email, or simply all lower cases first name (username is case insensitive).

Answer (score -3):

Open the main windows 8 Screen and move the mouse pointer to the right-side bottom and there click settings icon and now select accounts and select remove hotmail account

Comment: that's not what he asked. In this way you completely remove the association between your local account and the MS account