# Hide name and email address on Windows 10 login screen

Tags: windows-10

When I turn on my Windows 10 machine it shows my name and email address on the login screen. Anyone sitting next to me on the train can see who I am. How can I hide this information?

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/530303/how-to-hide-or-remove-email-address-from-windows-8-lockscreen

Comment: @Chenmunka Maybe, but that question was related to Windows 8. It might work though.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I do:

1. Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> then type `gpedit.msc`
2. Head to "Computer Configuration" -> "Windows Settings" -> "Security Settings" -> "Local Policies" -> "Security Options"
3. Find `Interactive logon: Do not display last user name`
4. Set it to "Enabled"

> If this policy is enabled, the name of the last user to successfully log on is not displayed in the Logon Screen.

[image]

Comment: Does this only work on Windows 10 Pro? gpedit.msc can't be found on my Win 10 Home machine.

Comment: @shrmn This method is indeed only for Pro editions, Home editions don't include the Local Group Policy Editor.

Comment: @nidunc The OP never specified his edition. If he does i'll update my answer.

Comment: @Insane No problem, was just answering shrmn's question.

Comment: @Insane I have the Home Edition of Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this article https://www.howtogeek.com/245944/how-to-hide-your-personal-information-on-the-windows-10-login-screen/

If you modify or add registry entries to:

```
Key: HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System

Entry: DWORD 32 dontdisplaylastusername value 1
Entry: DWORD 32 DontDisplayLockedUserID value 3
Entry: DWORD 32 dontdisplayusername     value 1
```

I am currently trying to remove the signin name during logging in. (fixed, reg line added above)

Theres also a switch in Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options > Show account details (toggle to off)

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: I have now been able to with, the release of 1703 remove signin name during login at the same key location with this entry: Entry: `DWORD 32 dontdisplayusername value 1` and I will reflect this in the above reply